# VS 2015 SOAP não funciona, mas no SOAPUi funciona normal

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, soap, soapclient

Na empresa existe um Serviço disponibilizado através de *WebService SOAP (IBM BPM)*. Não consigo resposta no *VS 2015* utilizando o *Web Reference* uma conexão com esse serviço. Sempre obtenho a resposta depois de muito tempo; O tempo limite da operação foi atingido.Mas se utilizar o *SOAPUi* consigo conectar normal no serviço. Na empresa possuí proxy mas já tentei ligar e desligar o proxy do windows 10 para testar,também adicionei o seguinte codigo:

```
WebProxy proxyObj = new WebProxy("proxy.url.com", 3128);
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("****", "****");
proxyObj.Credentials = networkCredential;
soapReference.Proxy = proxyObj;
```

Mas com esse código já cai no erro 403 de cara.
Testei fechar com o servidor um telnet e funcionou tudo normal, também tentei digitar a url direto e funcionou também.
Alguem tem ideia do que seja ?

Comment: 403 é quando o servidor rejeitou, não está faltando nada?

Comment: Esse soap você adicionou via WSDL? É um web reference?

Comment: Uma vez tive o mesmo problema e era meu proxy que barrava a resposta de ativação, ai tive que alterar no Web config com a tag expect100continue, depois dê uma olhada: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FelipeGrossi sim é um web reference.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa não está, consegui, com o mesmo código acessa até o web services da sefaz.

Comment: @JulioBorges Não funcionou. o mais estranho que na mesma rede, mas numa maquina windows 7 eu consigo conectar pelo vs 2015, meu programador relatou que antes de alguma atualização do windows 10. ocorreu esse problema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver criado um proxy reverso. o servidor responde a porta 9443 com https, por algum motivo o Windows 10 barrava. Solução foi criar um proxy reverso para a porta 443 padrão do https e resolveu tudo. Como o padrão da empresa é criar proxy reverso para todas as aplicações, ficou tudo de boa. Obg.

Answer (score 0):

Tente os seguintes passos:

- Desabilite todos os anti-vírus (inclusive o Windows Defender)
- Desabilite qualquer regra de firewall da máquina

Verifique se consegue chegar ao web service via browser, caso contrário, este código não irá funcionar.

Adicione essa linha:

```
soapReference.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Este comando força utilizar as credenciais utilizadas no windows. Caso não funcione, pode necessitar de acesso específico. Mas você pode ainda testar essa linha de comando:

```
soapReference.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Lembre de tirar suas configurações de autenticação existentes no código.

E verifique se não existe nenhuma restrição ao IP de destino. Um comando PING ou TELNET pode te ajudar.

Comment: é também não funcionou pra mim, esses comandos. o telnet fecha conexão normal e o ping também responde. Vou fazer uns testes com a equipe de redes na sexta-feira e posto alguma, resposta... @Felipe Grossi